# Identifying a search and replace operation in a file

Tags: algorithm

Imagine you have a source file in which someone has renamed one symbol to another using a simple textual replace.  The diff output on that file is typically quite long and not a very useful identifier of what's happened.  What you want to know is if the change was simply `s/a/b/g`, and if so what `a` and `b` are - you're not going to be telling this tool in advance, it's going to have to work it out for itself.  (You can assume here that 'a' and 'b' will not contain newlines, for the sake of argument.)

- What algorithm would you use to spot the search and replace? (easy)
- How would you make it work if several textual substitutions have taken place? (fairly easy)
- How would you write it to work on the diff output, without either of the original files being compared? (rather harder)
- How far can you take this with e.g. identifying a regexp match rather than a search/replace? (hard)
- In a file that contains this sort of change along with others, can you come up with a heuristic that would produce sed expression and a much shortened diff? (hard)

This is a question for those of you that like designing algorithms, but it's loosely based on an actual tool I'd like to use, so if you happen to know of a nice command line tool that does any of the above, bonus points. ;)

Comment: When you speak of regular expression, is it possible that part of the original string was reused in the replacement string ? This makes things significantly harder, I think, than a simple search by regex but replace by constant operation (you could perhaps write 2 different items in the list about it).

Comment: Just thought some more about it. Multiple textual substitutions does not sound as easy, because order may matter: `s/programmer/developer` followed by `s/program/executable` affects `programmer` differently. Can we suppose that operations only affected whole words (tokens for programming languages) ?

Comment: I'd be happy to see this solved with even the simple case, as long as your state the limitations.  I don't think spotting regexp matches in the general case is possible, and I suspect that if you have overlapping search-replace pairs any reasonable algorithm would come up with a different set of search/replaces than the author actually used.  But, given the lack of any solutions at the moment, even a partial answer is better than none at all, so just state your assumptions and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I think of right now:

- Run `/s/b/a/g` and diff the files (although that will obviously not spot an error in your regex)
- Make your own diff tool, that works the same as others, but accepts certain changes without showing it as a difference (i.e. if a line is different, and that line differs only by `a` on the one side and `b` on the other, don't mark the line)

Comment: Ah, but I meant an arbitrary change, one that you don't know at the point that you're running the tool.  Question updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

[Darcs (distributed version control system)](http://darcs.net) has special handling for such changes, so it does have an algorithm for it. So try looking in their documentation/asking them. Reusing the algorithm might be somewhat difficult since it's written in [Haskell](http://haskell.org) though.

Comment: The quickest of skims of the documentation suggests that you use a special replace command which does the replace and also flags that a replace has taken place  - http://darcs.net/manual/Best_practices.html#SECTION00514000000000000000 - rather than identifying it from its effects.  I may be wrong here, mind.